# .HTACCESS URL Format Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way for me to make a sort of universal URL like this:

```
/News?Today
/News?Archive

/News?703
/News?654
/News?308 (and so on)
```

Instead of:

```
/News?which=Today
/News?which=Archive

/News?which=703
/News?which=654
/News?which=308 (and so on)
```

A friend gave me a following suggestion, although he is not really sure this is the correct htaccess command:

```
RewriteRule /News?Today /News.php?which=Today
```

Comment: You need to use a rewritecond to look at the query string, it's not part of what the first parameter is compared to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex Ena.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Ena.php?open=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ Ena.php?open=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I have not been able to test your Solution yet; I will be in the coming days, so I will keep this Question updated.

Comment: Yes, I tried your Solution too now. And it keeps behaving like the other one. Is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: Sorry but you need to provide more details. What URL did you use for testing and what error did you get?

Comment: I did not get any error; `example.com/?Service` loads the Home Page, and not the Services Page.

Comment: So none of these 2 rules will impact URI that is `/?Service`. Can you paste your full .htaccess in question so that I can take a look and suggest you something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161037/discussion-between-de1an-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry difficult to understand code from comments. Can you please open a new question with coffee and clarify the problem so that I understand it better and may try to answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015928/htaccess-merging-two-rules

Answer (score -1):

Not tested:

```
RewriteRule ^/News?(.*)$ /News.php?which=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The whole thing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^/News?(.*)$ /News.php?which=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ifmodule tags are redundant on shared hosting servers.

Comment: Okay, so... ...I used this command (`RewriteRule ^/News?(.*)$ /News.php?which=$1 [L,QSA]`) and changed it to `RewriteRule ^/Ena?(.*)$ /Ena.php?open=$1 [L,QSA]` and put the DirectoryIndex to Ena.php so that I could load the pages like `/?Services`, `/?Prices` and so on. Now, it loads the default page nicely, but will not load any other one, id est: when I enter `/?Services` — it loads the default page, not the corresponding page. Help?

Comment: rewriterule doesn't match against the query string.