# .HTACCESS Merging Two Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Ena.php?open=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ Ena.php?open=%1 [L,QSA]
```

2.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule "^(\x41|\x4F|\x53|\x4C\x4A|\x4E\x4A|D\xC5\xBD|\xC5\xA0|\xC4\‌​x90|\xC4\x8C|\xC4\x8‌​6|\xC5\xBD|\x00-\xF4‌​8FBFBF|[A-Z])[^/]*$" "/? open=Encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0" [NE,L,QSA]
```

I need these two Rules properly merged together. They work well alone (when one is deleted, and the other one left), but together they won't.

Comment: In `/? open`, is the whitespace intentional?

Comment: Need clarification. What URLs are not working and what is the exact error?

Comment: The first part should open www.example.com/?Links (/?Stories, /?Latitudes, /?Astronomy, and so on). The second part should open normal short-hand links like www.example.com/Constellations+(Astronomy) Therefore, I think there might be a conflict between the Rules in the way they process links? The exact error is that only first part (**1.**) works as it should and not the **2.** The first part manages **/?Links** and the second one manages **/Constellations+(Astronomy)**

Comment: Nothing to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,END]

RewriteRule "^(\x41|\x4F|\x53|\x4[CE]\x4A|D\xC5\xBD|\xC5\xA0|\xC4(?:\‌​x90|\x8C|\x8‌​6)?|\xC5\xBD|\x00-\xF4‌​8FBFBF|[A-Z])[^/]*$" "/? open=Encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0" [NE,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Ena.php?open=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ Ena.php?open=%1 [L,QSA]
```

What happens if you put them in the order above? First, we check if requested content exists on system, and serve it as is. The `END` directive is new to httpd-2.4+, and short-circuits all other directives.

Comment: It loads the first part of code well, while the second one does not. What is the problem? Both Rules tolerate each other now, but they the second one with Ena.php won't work.

Comment: @De1an change `Ena.php?open=$1` to `/Ena.php?open=$1`.

Comment: Changed. Still the same thing.